# NUnit to JUnit for NUnitLite Runner

Tags: junit, nunit

I'm using NUnitLite runner in console application (according to this [example](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/NUnitLite-Runner.html)) to run my test on linux/mac.
I need to transform the results into JUnit format. I haven't found any flag/option how I can do the transformation only by using NUnitLite runner.

Another way would be to transform the results after the test run. I found xslt transformation [here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-transforms/tree/master/nunit3-junit), but I'm not sure, how to use it on linux/mac (I don't want to use mono in this case).

Did I miss something in NUniteLite runner or is there a simple way to run xslt transformation on linux/mac I could use?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Not clear what the question means. Are you asking how to write a program that transforms the XML using XSLT, how to run it on your platform, or what? Why is linux / mac a problem for you exactly, if you're already able to run nunitlite on the platform?

Comment: @Charlie, thanks for the comment. I changed the question and hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's not universal, but worked for me on linux(Ubuntu)/mac:

```
xsltproc -o PATH_TO/JUNIT_FILE.xml PATH_TO/nunit3-junit.xslt PATH_TO/TestResult.xml
```

Where "nunit3-junit.xslt" comes from  [nunit /
nunit-transforms](https://nunit3-junit.xslt)
 and for more info about xsltproc see [here](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/libxslt/xsltproc.html).